# Inverse Image of a Subfunctor

Tags: category-theory

If Y is a subfunctor of X and $f:X\rightarrow X'$ is a natural transformation.  Then how is the inverse image of a natural transformation *$f^{-1}$* defined?

I mean, the given definition is:
on objects A of the category in question, $f^{-1}[Y]:=f(A)^{-1}(Y(A))$.

What I don't understand is: Why does $f(A)^{-1}$ make any sense?  If we are working with the category $Alg_k$ then what can $f(A)^{-1}$ mean? Specifically, f is defined on the images of objects of X(-), X(A) for example, but A is not even in the same category as f should be defined in?

**Note:**  If it helps, X is a member of $[Alg_k,Sets]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $Y$ is a subfunctor of $X'$ and that $f : X \to X'$ is a natural transformation. Then $f^{-1}(Y) := Y \times_{X'} X$, and this is the subfunctor of $X$ which is given by mapping an object $A$ to the set of those $s \in X(A)$ such that $f(s) \in X'(A)$ lies in $Y(A)$.

Comment: Ya exactly.  I think I was just confused by the notation, as it omits the X(-); usually I denote my natural transformations as $f_{X(-)}$ instead of $f(-)$.  Thanks :) the rest makes sense now :)